# json_encode returning null if array not accessed before

Tags: php, json

In my code I build an array and encode it using json_encode,
json_encode returns null for this array unless I insert the instruction "echo $responce->rows[0][0];" before encoding, if I comment out this row json_encode returns null!

Can someone find out why?

```
echo $responce->rows[0][0];
echo json_encode($responce);
```

It has this behaviour with this encoded json, but works for different arrays:

```
{"rows":[{"id":"33UD","cell":["Great Yarmouth Borough Council",5875732.23,61.01]},
{"id":"41UE","cell":["Newcastle-Under-Lyme District Council",2514111.76,20.24]},
{"id":"36UF","cell":["Ryedale District Council",96439.18,1.8]},{"id":"00CM","cell":
["Sunderland City Council",16473262.71,58.48]}]}
```

Comment: can you add more of your code?

Comment: What does `var_dump($responce)` output?

Comment: do you get your data from a database?

Comment: Should we guess at your code?

Answer (score 2):

You will get `null` returned by `json_encode` if your array values are not encoded to  `utf8` (so they are not safe for `json_encode`)

if you get your data from a db try using:

`mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')` 
before your `SELECT` statement